# haproxy httpchk with authentication

Tags: authentication, haproxy

Is it possible to do health check httpchk and pass credentials?

I supposed to try to pass user name and password and if that fails to change server state to down.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer to myself it might be helpful to someone else. This is what I've done.

$ echo -n "my_username:my_password" | base64
I got this string: TkxCX0hCOkhCREhCX0NoZWNr

After that I put the following int my conf:

option httpchk GET /CSHRIS/WS/Service.asmx HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ TkxCX0hCOkhCREhCX0NoZWNr

Comment: Where did you put it in the configuration? Which section?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same concern when I was trying to load balance between my Elastic search nodes,

1. Use curl and grab the Authentication header,

   curl -v http://username:password@ip_or_domain_name:9200/path_to_the_heath_check

> ...
> GET /path_to_the_heath_check HTTP/1.1
> Host: ip_or_domain_name:9200
> Authorization: Basic someBas64encoDedUsernameAndPassword==
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> ...
> 2. Derive the Healthcheck config

```
option httpchk GET /path_to_heath_check HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ someBas64encoDedUsernameAndPassword==
```